# How to get Appcelerator Studio to use different node js version

Tags: node.js, appcelerator

I have other node js projects that use version 6.10.2.  Appcelerator, to my knowledge, can only use up to version 4.6.x.  I'm using a node version manager (nvm) to switch between 6.10.2 and 4.6.2 but Appcelerator always uses the 6.10.2 version making my Appcelerator projects not compile correctly.

I've verified that *nvm* is switching correctly.  I've added the the location of 4.6.2 to the Nod Js *Node Executable" field under Appcelerator preferences.

But when I build the project in Appcelerator, I get:

```
Node.js
Node.js Version             = 6.10.2
npm Version                 = 2.15.11

FATAL ERROR: v8::ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal.
```

It works if only have node js v4.6.2 installed, but I need both available (which is why I'm using something like *nvm*).

Comment: Can you set system or default node version v4.6.X?

Comment: I can but Appcelerator appears to search for node.exe and uses whichever it finds first.  I tried several things in Appcelerator to tell it which version to use but to no avail.  Ultimately I wrote a batch file that renames the node.exe to node.tmp in the version I _wasn't_ using and updates the PATH environment variable appropriately.